# What is the difference between database storage API and DOM storage API

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, web-storage

From the WebView documentation, it says:

1. `setDatabaseEnabled` sets whether the **database storage API** is enabled.
2. `setDomStorageEnabled` sets whether the **DOM storage API** is enabled.

So I want to ask what is **database storage API** and what is **DOM storage API**? What are their differences?

Answer (score 1):

`setDatabaseEnabled` refers to the Web SQL Database API which allows webpages to store data in a relational database. However, this API is actually deprecated.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database

`setDomStorageEnabled` refers to the HTML5 Web Storage API, which allows web pages to store key-value pairs of data, similar to cookies, but with larger storage capacity.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage